# AMQ9999 occuring in AMQERR01.LOG

Tags: ibm-mq

I have the following error showing up in AMQERR01.LOG

```
AMQ9999: Channel 'MGATESrvChannel' to host 'Mgate (127.0.0.1)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 1060(4364) for channel
'MGATESrvChannel' ended abnormally. The host name is 'Mgate (127.0.0.1)'; in
some cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
```

This error is preceded with following message:

```
AMQ9508: Program cannot connect to the queue manager.

EXPLANATION:
The connection attempt to queue manager 'MGATE.QM' failed with reason code
2059.
ACTION:
Ensure that the queue manager is available and operational.
```

According to what I have been told this can be caused by an application that is using queue manager, however, it seems to me that this has more to do with the way that manager was set up or similar. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2059 says that a connection request was received and refused because the QMgr was not available.  We used to see this a lot when the listener was run as a separate process or when inetd was used to start channels.  This is because the listener was there to accept the connection but the QMgr processes were not.

Now that the listener is run as a child process of the QMgr, it is quite rare to see this on the WMQ error logs though clients commonly see it.  This is because when the listener is run as a child process of the QMgr, there is nothing listening to receive the connection request and it bounces off of the host's IP stack before ever getting to MQ code.

The AMQ9999 message says that a channel program, one of the QMgr's child processes, died or was killed and this caused the channel to terminate.  There are many reasons for a channel process to die including being killed by the OS if resources are short, or being killed by a human operator.  Other than that the most common way they can die due to running in trusted or fastpath mode and the attached program corrupts them.

It would help to narrow down the field to know the details of the QMgr in question - version and fix pack, how the listeners are started, channel settings, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Unfortunately I can not provide more details because the client did not provide us with any specifics. However, it seems that the client has found the solution on its own with making some changes to the MQ Manager on their side which apparently solved the problem they thought was caused by application that was using MQ.

Comment: Then I'd recommend deleting the question.  Without question details and an answer that is only speculative, it won't be of much help to future readers.  Unless you do think the response is helpful, in which case please accept and vote it.

Answer (score -1):

Start your listener up, you may check the Control property for that channel, so it start up automatically when the Queue Manager restart.